# Google Billing Library - Processing Purchases - Verify Purchase and granting entitlements

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, entitlements

I am new to the implementation of Google's Billing library and using this system to make subscriptions inside my app. In the android documentation link https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process it has been said that we need to verify the purchase and grant entitlements to the user.

The documentation has not clearly explained about the process on how to implement it. Also, i could not find any links explaining the same. I am not sure on how to verify the purchase and then grant entitlements to the user in the app. Can you please provide suggestions/sample code on how to verify the purchase before granting entitlements to the user?

Comment: did you completed this thing? if yes can you post the code?